# Dart remove an object in list

Tags: dart

I want to remove an object from my list but I do not see how.
I want to remove objects that have the same type and keep the greatest distance by type.

Here is my code:

```
int userDistance = 851;
final String chargesJson = '''[
    {
        "type" : 1,
        "distance": 800,
        "setting": 1122,
        "bond" : 44
    },
    {
        "type" : 1,
        "distance": 850,
        "setting": 1076,
        "bond" : 50
    },
    {
        "type" : 2,
        "distance": 800,
        "setting": 1336,
        "bond" : 37
    },
    {
        "type" : 2,
        "distance": 900,
        "setting": 1299,
        "bond" : 39
    }
]
''';
final List charges = json.decode(chargesJson);

Map searchCharges(int userDistance) {
  Map result = {};

  // List all charges that are less than userDistance
  // Remove all charges that are higher
  List positiveDistanceDiff = charges.where((c) => userDistance - c['distance'] >= 0 ).toList();
  print('positiveDistanceDiff : $positiveDistanceDiff');
```

I have this :

```
positiveDistanceDiff : [{type: 1, distance: 800, setting: 1122, bond: 44}, {type: 1, distance: 850, setting: 1076, bond: 50}, {type: 2, distance: 800, setting: 1336, bond: 37}]
```

But I only want one object per type that has the longest distance.
So In my exemple I want to have a list without

```
{type: 1, distance: 800, setting: 1122, bond: 44}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I am not sure I understand fully your question since by your own logic, you should also remove the "type: 2" entry with a distance of 800?

Also, I have made the code so it creates a new list where the values has been filtered.

```
import 'dart:convert';

const String chargesJson = '''[
    {
        "type" : 1,
        "distance": 800,
        "setting": 1122,
        "bond" : 44
    },
    {
        "type" : 1,
        "distance": 850,
        "setting": 1076,
        "bond" : 50
    },
    {
        "type" : 2,
        "distance": 800,
        "setting": 1336,
        "bond" : 37
    },
    {
        "type" : 2,
        "distance": 900,
        "setting": 1299,
        "bond" : 39
    }
]
''';

void main() {
  final charges = json.decode(chargesJson) as List<dynamic>;

  final filteredList = charges
      .cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
      .fold(<int, Map<String, dynamic>>{},
          (Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> map, element) {
        final type = element['type'] as int;

        if (!map.containsKey(type) ||
            (map[type]['distance'] as int) < (element['distance'] as int)) {
          map[type] = element;
        }

        return map;
      })
      .values
      .toList();

  filteredList.forEach(print);
  // {type: 1, distance: 850, setting: 1076, bond: 50}
  // {type: 2, distance: 900, setting: 1299, bond: 39}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time I choose this solution ! That's very helpful :) I did not understand the part with the cast and the fold especially what is put in it ... do you have a documentation on this point to help me understand

Comment: I am using [`cast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/cast.html) to make each `dynamic` element in the `List<dynamic>` into a `Map<String, dynamic>` which I know is allowed based on the JSON. `dynamic` means the type can first be determined on runtime so we need to cast it to some other type on runtime if we want type safety. I really hate `dynamic` so I always try to cast as much as possible.

Comment: The [`fold`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) method is used to convert the `List` into a `Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>>` where the key is `type`-id and value is the whole `Map` element. Fold takes an object as argument which will be used together with all the elements in the list so you can insert data inside the e.g. map while you go through the list. I am also use the map to identify if I have already seen an "type" before and if that is the case, I will compare it and see if I should replace the value in the map.

Comment: After the fold() method has been running it returns the map object. I then takes all the values from this map and insert them into a list. Since I know this map only contain one map object for each "type" (and I have ensured that value in the map is the one with the longest distance) then we gets a fine list with only one map object of each type and with the longest distance. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your list into a map using as keys the distance type

```dart
...
  var positiveDistanceDiff = charges.where((c) => userDistance - c['distance'] >= 0 ).toList();
  var dist = parseDistance(positiveDistanceDiff);
  print(dist); //Prints:  {1: {type: 1, distance: 850, setting: 1076, bond: 50}, 2: {type: 2, distance: 800, setting: 1336, bond: 37}}
  //Use dist.values if you dont want any keys
}

Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> parseDistance(List<dynamic> distances) {
  var map = <int, Map<String, dynamic>>{};
  for (var distance in distances) {
    map.update(
        distance['type'],
        (currentValue) => currentValue['distance'] > distance['distance']
            ? currentValue
            : distance,
        ifAbsent: () => distance);
  }
  return map;
}
```

The updates methods updates the current value only if it is less than the new value.

As commented you can use `dist.values` to get a list of the values that you want.